# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to write a query that returns an "Estimated Annual Value", and for this, I am using a Case statement. There are two inner joins involved in the query.

So, the query and gives me result when I am running this piece:

```
select Users.Id, Name, PhoneNumber, Email, Currency, count(*) as TotalOrders, sum(TotalCustomerAmount) as TotalOrderValue, avg(TotalCustomerAmount) as AverageOrderValue, TsCreate as RegistrationDate, max(TsOrderPlaced) as LastOrderDate, min(TsOrderPlaced) as FirstOrderDate, 
CASE 
    When PromotionsEnabled = 0 then 'Y'
    When PromotionsEnabled = 1 then 'n'
    else 'undefined'
end as Promotions,
/*CASE
    When ((DATEDIFF(day, max(TsOrderPlaced), min(TsOrderPlaced)) >= 6) AND (count(*) > 3)) then  ((sum(TotalCustomerAmount)/(DATEDIFF(day, max(TsOrderPlaced), min(TsOrderPlaced))))*365) 
    Else '-'
end as EstimatedAnnualValue*/
from AspNetUsers with (nolock)
    inner join Orders with (nolock) on Orders.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id and Orders.WhiteLabelConfigId = @WhiteLabelConfigId
                                    and Orders.OrderState in (2,3,4,12)     
    inner join UserWhiteLabelConfigs with (nolock) on UserWhiteLabelConfigs.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id and Orders.WhiteLabelConfigId = @WhiteLabelConfigId
where AspNetUsers.Discriminator = 'ApplicationUser'
group by Users.Id, Name, Number, Currency, Email, TsCreate, PromotionsEnabled
```

*But the problem comes when I am running this with the second CSAE statement, is it because I cannot use the aggregate function before GROUP BY? I am also thinking of using a Subquery*
Looking fr some help!!

Comment: All paths in a case *expression* should lead to the same datatype. What do you want to happen in the `ELSE`?  `-` Is not a number.

Comment: Okay, the DATEDIFF returns an int and I think the CASE statement returns the same as well? But I can be wrong. The else return nothing, just a blank. Is that the issue? @HoneyBadger

Comment: You have a MySQL tag but code that would fail in MySQL.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  I switched the tag to SQL Server, because your code looks like SQL Server.  You also need to explain the logic you want the query to run.

Comment: Thanks, @GordonLinoff. It worked now. So, the only problem with this was that the second Null was returning a string, whereas it should return int/double.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @RachitRastogi, the `ELSE` doesn't return 'nothing', nor a 'blank'. It returns a `'-'`, which is a string

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregation functions.  For instance, if you want `'Y'` only when all values are `0` or `NULL`:

```
(case when max(PromotionsEnabled) = 0 then 'Y'
      when max(PromotionsEnabled) = 1 then 'N'
      else 'undefined'
 end) as Promotions,
```

I'm not sure if this is the logic you want (because that detail is not in the question).  However, this shows that you can use aggregation functions in a `case` **expression**.